# How can I avoid Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I'm starting to learn java and this is my program:

```
package Hello;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

I opened the terminal and went to my working directory:

```
cd /path/to/directory/
```

Then compiled the program:

```
javac Hello.java
```

Then attempted to run it:

```
java Hello
```

And I get this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Hello
```

But if I remove `package Hello;` everything works.

Why does removing that line make the program work and what can I do to make my program work and still keep the package line?

I looked around, and can't find a clear answer to my question. People say

> type `java -cp . Hello` and don't use `.class` after `Hello`

but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try running `java Hello.Hello` (that is, including the package name).

Comment: u need to consider the package also.by the way, package name should be  start with small letter.

Comment: @Emd4600 I tried that and get the same error

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a legitimate question.

Comment: I'll balance out that down vote... I agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your package is "Hello", java assumes it is located in folder named "Hello".

So if you did:

```
cd /path/to/directory/
mkdir Hello
mv Hello.java Hello/
javac Hello/Hello.java
java Hello.Hello
```

It should work. But I agree with Pitchers, package name should be lowercase.

Comment: Thank you! I understand my mistake now